# Ignoring node_modules when using flow

Tags: flowtype

I am using `flow` within my React Native application, the initial startup of flow is incredibly slow because it is traversing through my `node_modules` directory. Flow is reporting masses of errors coming from these third party libraries, which I am unable to fix.

Can I tell flow to ignore any errors within `node_modules`? I have this in my config file:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
```

However, flow now tells throws
`react-native Required module not found`. Weirdly enough, this error isn't picked up when importing React.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a folder in your projects root called `flow-typed` and create declaration files for your modules in there. So in this case you would create the file:

**flow-typed/react-native.js**

```
// @flow

declare module 'react-native' {
    /* declarations go here... */
}
```

The reason that React doesn't complain when included is that flow comes with declarations out of the box (https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js) the same way it comes with declarations for the javascript and browser standard libraries.

Word of warning, though, it is not exactly trivial to write these declaration files. For inspiration look at the declarations Flow comes with, and the ones in the https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed repository.

Comment: Absolutely correct! I used `flow-typed` to automatically generate declaration files for all modules within my `devDependencies`. However, react-native is a `dependency` so I had to manually create the file.

Comment: @Dan AFAIK react-native comes with flow types - perhaps you were/are using a too new version of flow? I think they are still on v0.40.0.

Comment: you use flow-typed to create the declaration stubs if you don't want to write them by hand: `flow-typed create-stub <library-name>`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell flow that I want to ignore a library in node_modules and also not provide any flow-typed declaration? I want flow to totally ignore that library, whenever I interface with it, flow can consider it valid. I take that risk. Can it be done?